# Open a file from a remote network share

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-io

I am trying to open a file from a server

I currently have

```
Dim attachedFilePath As String = "\\myserver\myshare\test.txt"

File.Open(attachedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

This does not open a file.

However, if I change the path to be local then there is no issue.

```
Dim attachedFilePath As String = "c:\...\test.txt"
```

So, is there a way to open a file from remote storage?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: no exception, the line appears to execute with no issue but notepad doesn't open and nothing appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File.Open is for reading the contents of a file. Use Process.Start to launch the default application for that file type

```
Dim Path = "\\myserver\myshare\test.txt"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path)
```

Comment: +1 for reading the question AND comments and figuring out what he really meant, not what he said.